# How to concatenate two object and replace the values?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to concatenate two objects. I need to merge the two object and based on the "beforeVist" object value within the arrow.

My two objects down below:

```
const beforeVist = {
  name : '<<name>>',
  age : '<<age>>',
  place : '<<place>>'
};

const afterVist = {
  name : 'Robin',
  age : 22,
  place : 'Mars'
}

var Updated = {...afterVist, ...beforeVist};
console.log(Updated)
```

when I'm trying do console.log() function output below,

```
{
    name : 'Robin',
    age : 22,
    place : 'Mars'
}
```

this is what my expected output is. I'm not sure that it is the right way.

Thanks advance!!!

Comment: That's the right way. maybe you want to do, `{...beforeVisit, ...afterVisit }`

Comment: i need to take beforeVisit placeholder <<age>> and replace with afterVisit value. should remove the arrow

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
const a = {p1: 12, p2: 23}
const b = {p2: 34, p3: 'adfa'}
let c = Object.assign(b, a)
// c contains:
{p2: 23, p3: "adfa", p1: 12}
```

If you care about immutability, you can provide separate "result" object:

```
const res = Object.assign({}, b, a)
```

// a and b still hold the original values

NOTE: properties ORDER will be driven from left-to-right ("p2" is the first prop in B, but second in A), but the VALUES from right-to-left(result.p2 contains value from the rightMost object with such property - ie A.p2 overrides B.p2

Answer (score 0):

It is the right way. You should use [object sprad](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread)

```
let merged = {...obj1, ...obj2};
```

**Method for ES5 and Earlier**

```
for (var attrname in obj2) { obj1[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
```

Because **<< >>** are **always** at the **first two places and the last two places** we can simply slice and then reassign the value.

```js
const beforeVist = {
    name: '<<name>>',
    age: '<<age>>',
    place: '<<place>>'
};

const afterVist = {
    name: '<<Robin>>',
    age: '<<22>>',
    place: '<<Mars>>'
}

var Updated = {...beforeVist, ...afterVist };

Object.entries(Updated).forEach(([key, value]) => {

    let val = value.slice(2, value.length - 2);
    Updated[key] = val;
})


console.log(Updated)
```

Comment: i need to take beforeVisit placeholder <<age>> and replace with afterVisit value. should remove the arrow

Comment: You should be using `.forEach()` instead of `.map()` if you just want to iterate. `.map()` is used when you want to transform each element in the array to a new element, which will then return a new array

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are just overwriting the properties from `afterVist` with the properties in `beforeVist`, and since the property names are the same, you're essentially just making a shallow copy. This is more evident if your `afterVist` has different property names to `beforeVist` (and why I've provided different property names in `beforeVist` below - to show that they don't have to be the same and that the value is grabbed based on the key specified in `<<key>>`)

Instead, you can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) by [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of your original object, and using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on the keys to extract the key name like so:

```js
const beforeVist = { myName: '<<name>>', myAge: '<<age>>', myPlace: '<<place>>' }; 
const afterVist = { name: 'Robin', age: 22, place: 'Mars' };

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(beforeVist).map(([key, value]) => [
  key,
  value.replace(/<<([^>>]*)>>/, (_, g) => afterVist[g])
]));
console.log(result);
```